Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'some View' conform to 'TabContent'
How do I understand this? I added a couple of lines not affecting the structure and got this error.  The last changes I made were .alert in the second tab. And otherwise literally the same code worked yesterday, and today it's no longer working ...
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var alarmViewModel: AlarmViewModel
    @ObservedObject var wakeUpIntervalData: WakeUpModel
    @ObservedObject var soundSettingsViewData: SoundSettingsViewModel
    @State private var selectedTab = 2
    
    @State private var isEditingNewAlarm = false
    @State private var editingAlarmIndex: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            // MARK: - Statistic Tab
            NavigationView {
                Color("BackgroundColorSet").ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "waveform")
                Text("Statistic")
            }.tag(1)
            
            // MARK: - Alarm Tab
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        ForEach(alarmViewModel.alarms.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: AlarmSettingsView(
                                    alarmViewModel: alarmViewModel,
                                    wakeUpIntervalData: wakeUpIntervalData,
                                    soundSettingsViewData: soundSettingsViewData,
                                    delayData: DelayViewModel(),
                                    alarmIndex: index
                                )
                                .onAppear {
                                    alarmViewModel.loadAlarm(at: index)
                                }
                            ) {
                                AlarmWidgetView(alarm: alarmViewModel.alarms[index])
                            }
                        }
                        
                        // Кнопка добавления нового будильника
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: AlarmSettingsView(
                                alarmViewModel: alarmViewModel,
                                wakeUpIntervalData: wakeUpIntervalData,
                                soundSettingsViewData: soundSettingsViewData,
                                delayData: DelayViewModel()
                            ),
                            isActive: $isEditingNewAlarm
                        ) {
                            Button(action: {
                                alarmViewModel.resetCurrentAlarm()
                                isEditingNewAlarm = true
                            }) {
                                Text("+")
                                    .fontWeight(.thin)
                                    .font(.system(size: 54))
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 46)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("BackgroundColorSet"))
                                    .background(Color("StringColorSet"))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .padding()
                            }
                        }
                    }.background(Color("BackgroundColorSet"))
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $alarmViewModel.showAlert) { // Добавьте отображение AlarmAlertView здесь
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Wake Up!"),
                        message: Text("It's time to wake up!"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("Snooze +10 min"), action: {
                            // Ваш код для отсрочки
                            Task {
                                await alarmViewModel.stopLiveActivity() // Остановить текущую Live Activity
                                await alarmViewModel.startLiveActivity() // Запустить новую Live Activity с отсрочкой
                            }
                        }),
                        secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Stop"), action: {
                            // Ваш код для остановки будильника
                            alarmViewModel.stopLiveActivity() // Остановить текущую Live Activity
                        })
                    )
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "alarm")
                Text("Alarm")
            }.tag(2)
            
            // MARK: - Settings Tab
            NavigationView {
                Color("BackgroundColorSet").ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                Text("Settings")
            }.tag(3)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    HomeView(
        alarmViewModel: AlarmViewModel(),
        wakeUpIntervalData: WakeUpModel(),
        soundSettingsViewData: SoundSettingsViewModel()
    )
}


Could the fact that I changed the .alert have an impact?

There might be an extra parenthesis there.

Note NavigationView is deprecated, use NavigationStack instead. Also check the meaning of NavigationView{  Color("BackgroundColorSet").ignoresSafeArea()  } inside another NavigationView

There may be an issue with the view model AlarmViewModel. I was able to get it to compile when I used the following skeleton implementation:
class AlarmViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let alarms = ["One", "Two"]
    @Published var showAlert = false
    func loadAlarm(at: Int) {}
    func resetCurrentAlarm() {}
    func stopLiveActivity() {}
    func startLiveActivity() {}
}

You may want to check that the real class really has implementations for all the functions being called.
Even then, there are still two compiler warnings:

the way the NavigationLink is being used is deprecated
warnings about no async operation when calling alarmViewModel.stopLiveActivity() and alarmViewModel.startLiveActivity() from within the primaryButton callback.

If you add async to the stop/start functions then this leads to an error in the way stopLiveActivity is being called in the secondaryButton callback action. So this may be the real cause of the problem.
